# object oriented javascript how to create a static class for constants

Tags: javascript

I've decided to put all my constants in a neat class called constants, and would like to access its members with the dot operator.

So far I've tried:

```
function Constants(){
    Constants.style = {};
    Constants.style.border_sides = 20;
    Constants.style.button_width = 17;
    // ...
}
```

And later

```
Constants = new Constants();
```

and

```
{
    $('#button').width(Constants.style.button_width);
}
```

That resulted in a

> Can't access button_width of undefined.

I would use JSON to declare the constants, but I like comments in my code.
Would someone explain javascript's OO?

Comment: The object literal suits my purposes pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You replace the `Constants` function with an instance of `Constants`. And you applied your constants to the function, not an instance of Constants or the prototype. So you effectively wiped your constants away.

I'd argue just use an object literal

```
var constants = {
   style: {
        border_sides: 20
   }
};
```

Keep in mind there's nothing actually constant about either approaches. Anyone can easily change the "constant" values. If you want truly constant data, you might want to use getters/setters, `Object.defineProperty` or the module pattern.

Comment: And nowadays, you can use `const` if you're environment supports EcmaScript 2015

Answer (score 5):

If you want a "class" with both static and instance methods:

```
function ClassName(){

}

ClassName.prototype = { //Put instance methods here
   instanceMethod1 : function(){},

   instanceMethod2 : function(){}
};

ClassName.staticMethod1 = function(){};
ClassName.staticMethod2 = function(){};

var a = new ClassName();

a.staticMethod1; //undefined
a.instanceMethod1; //function(){};

ClassName.staticMethod1 //function(){};
```

Comment: So that's how I add static and instance methods, do instance and static variables work the same way?

Comment: Hmm.. you can look at explanation for static members here: http://java.about.com/od/workingwithobjects/a/staticfields.htm It's in java (and yes I know javascript and java are vastly different types of languages) but it's the same principle

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just consider using literals?

```
var Constants = {
    style: {
        border_sides: 20,
        button_width: 17
    }
}
```

Even if you are willing to consider using the `construction function`, replace `Constants` with `this`

```
function Constants(){
    this.style = {};
    this.style.border_sides = 20;
    this.style.button_width = 17;
    // ...
}
```

You don't need to do any `new Constants()` for literals (1st example). Just start using right away.

For 2nd example `(constructor function)` you need to do `var constants = new Constants()`.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript everyting is an object, so you're adding properties to the Constants function within the function.

To get the effect you want write:

```
var Constants = {
  someText: 'text1',
  someInt: 1
};
```

And to access, is simply:

```
var text = Constants.someText;
```